# angular 2 internationalisation

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm using Angular 2 (typescript) with spring-boot at backend.
I want to add i18n feature in this.

I have below 2 ways to implement it.
1. Load resource bundle in spring-boot and provide it to Angular 2.
Problem: After loading resource bundle in spring-boot, not able to figure out how to use it in Angular 2 code.
2. Fetch user locale from spring-boot via rest api call and then load Angular 2 with that locale.
Problem: After fetching user locale from spring-boot via rest api call, not able to figure out how to load (or bootstrap) Angular 2 with this locale. In Angular doc [website](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler), locale is hardcoded in main.ts and app.module.ts. Can we make it dynamic after fetching from rest call and load app again?

Comment: Did you get a chance to have a look https://angular.io/guide/i18n#other-translation-formats ?

Comment: These are just translation file formats. I can choose any. But its not related to my question.

Comment: Have you had a look at [https://github.com/ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)? This should allow to implement an appropriate loader, such as `TranslateHttpLoader` to retrieve the translations from the Spring backend.